# Google Maps: Get coordinates of a street block

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API, and I want to be able to draw a line down a street from one block to the next.

For example, I want to be able to draw a line from the 1000 block of Main street to the 1100 block of Main Street.

When I enter 1100 Main street, I get the address of a building at 1100 N Main Street. I would like to get the coordinates of the center of the intersection at 1100 N Main street (or the center of the street at 1100 N Main St if no intersection exists there).

Basically I want to force the API to return a RANGE_INTERPOLATED result instead of a ROOFTOP result. Is there some parameter that I can pass to Google Maps to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not use an event listener with the map object and the click event, and return the lat/lng from location where you clicked (that would be the more precise way of getting coordinates).

Comment: I want to be able to stream an RSS feed and fetch coordinates based on the locations given in the RSS feed.