# Geolocation: How to get a uniqueID for a street/block?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, mapbox, openstreetmap

**Background** I'm a bit new to google maps/mapping sdks in general. I want to create a street by street "heat" map of an area on iOS. As an easy to understand example, let's say it will be for the purpose of mapping daily puppy sightings in a city. The data changes regularly, we need to show that certain streets have more puppy traffic than others.

Similar to the ones pictured here
[image]
https://blog.mapbox.com/spotangels-mobile-parking-maps-30db4b10aee7

And here
[image]
https://www.trulia.com/local/san-francisco-ca/type:traffic_volume_live

To do this, I would like to get a unique ID for each street block. 
Something like this: 
[image]

**Question:** How can I tell when a user entered a unique street? How can I get a unique street ID?

**Related side question**: If it's not possible in google maps, links to doing it in OpenStreetMap or Mapbox would be appreciated.

**Places I've looked**

- [How to get an use an unique identifier for each street in google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055830/how-to-get-an-use-an-unique-identifier-for-each-street-in-google-maps-api)

  - Issue: No answer
- [Highlighting whole street with some maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155032/highlighting-whole-street-with-some-maps-api?rq=1)

  - Issue: Info from 2010
- [Google Maps: Get coordinates of a street block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484924/google-maps-get-coordinates-of-a-street-block?rq=1)

  - Issue: No answer
- [Get street graph for a game using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514748/get-street-graph-for-a-game-using-google-maps-api?rq=1)

  - Issue: Info from 2012
- [Map Highlight Odd/Even Side of Street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886715/map-highlight-odd-even-side-of-street?rq=1)

  - Issue: Unanswered
- [Display traffic data with maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312914/display-traffic-data-with-maps?rq=1)

  - Issue: Unanswered
- [How to get only street/road coordinates via reverse geocoding (Google Maps API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911682/how-to-get-only-street-road-coordinates-via-reverse-geocoding-google-maps-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

  - Streets in a radius
- [How to get all roads around a given location in OpenStreetMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322823/how-to-get-all-roads-around-a-given-location-in-openstreetmap)

  - Partial solution OSM

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/plan-replace-geographic-coordinates-earth-unique-strings-three-words-180949946/)?

Comment: Isn't lat & lon already a good unique "ID" for a street or block?

@geocodezip I really hope he is *not* looking for such a proprietary system.

Comment: OSM does *not* have [permanend IDs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Permanent_ID). However it is possible to construct something similar using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Permanent_ID). Not sure how good (i..e how permanent) this solution will be, though.

Comment: The question is really broad, trying to get the OP to clarify.

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry about the lack of clarity. Nope, I'm not referring to lat/longs. I was wondering if I can somehow get an id for the street or somehow tell when a user entered a new block on the same street. I added a photo to hopefully clear things up a bit.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [nearestRoads endpoint of the Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest)

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable with OSM data.

Retrieve the streets around you (e.g. using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and the *around* query). Determine the [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) you are currently driving on, then split it at each intersection [*node*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). Now you have street segments similar to your second image. The start and end *node ID* of each segment could be used as (temporary¹) identifier.

¹ temporary, because IDs in OSM can change eventually.